# HTML file not sending to HP ePrint App for Print from Android App

Tags: android, android-print-framework

I tried for text(*.txt) file print its working good but when I try for HWML file its not working.  Here is my code.

**Home.java**

```
public class Home extends Activity{

    private static final String FileName = "file.html";

    Button button1;

    final File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(), FileName);

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.home);

        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Uri uri = Uri.fromFile( file );
                Intent intent = new Intent ("org.androidprinting.intent.action.PRINT");
                intent.setDataAndType( uri, "text/html" );
                startActivity(intent);
                //startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

            }
        });      

    }
}
```

Comment: is print html whole text like <html>.....</html>?

Comment: not code(<html>..</html>) ,i need output of html file like what we will see in browser.

Comment: your output print html source code for now?

Comment: This is my HTML code `<html>
<body>
<img src="subba.jpg" width="150" height="150">
</body>
</html>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you directly pass image don't need to html text. try below code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent ("org.androidprinting.intent.action.PRINT");
intent.setDataAndType( Uri.fromFile(new File("assets/subba.jpg"), "image/jpeg" );
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: I want path from sdcard so i replaced `assets` to `sdcard`, its working good. Thanks.